# Add repo to Pharo smalltalk without specifying package

Tags: repository, smalltalk, pharo

I've read that It's a good experience to use a fresh image every day and load your code from a repo. And the only way I know to add repo is do select package and press "+Repository". But can I add a repo when I have a clean image and no packages??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Lukas described is standard practice. I would start there. But the literal answer to your question is e.g.:

```
repo := MCHttpRepository
    location: 'http://www.squeaksource.com/[whatever]'
    user: ''
    password: ''.
MCRepositoryGroup default addRepository: repo.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Gofer](http://www.lukas-renggli.ch/blog/gofer) expression to load packages. Gofer automatically assigns the specified repositories to the loaded packages. Have a look at this collection of [scripts](https://github.com/renggli/builder/tree/master/scripts) to see how this works in practice.

Also [Metacello](http://code.google.com/p/metacello/) automatically adds the necessary repositories, but requires you to create a configuration of the packages, versions and repositories first.